# JSTL support in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

Though I know that there are [some limitations in the JSP support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations), I want to use JSP with JSTL tags in Spring Boot web application.

An extract of my JSP file:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

...

<c:catch var="ex">
    <c:if test="${!fn:contains(param.template,'../') && !fn:startsWith(param.template,'/')}">
        <c:import url=    ...
```

So, I added to the following dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, If accessing to the jsp, the exception is thrown:

```
2017-08-14 13:09:32.259 ERROR 2376 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be
 resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:80) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1448) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:145) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:203) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:601) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.t246osslab.easybuggy4sb.core.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.t246osslab.easybuggy4sb.core.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.t246osslab.easybuggy4sb.core.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(EncodingFilter.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Does anyone know the solution or workaround?

**Environment:**

- Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

I don't need alternative solutions using Thymeleaf.

---

EDIT:

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `git clone https://github.com/k-tamura/easybuggy4sb.git`
2. `cd easybuggy4sb`
3. Add the following dependencies to pom.xml.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Add the following property to src/main/resources/application.properties (in order to avoid exceptions during startup):

   ```
   server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar
   ```
5. Add test.jsp file into src/main/webapp:

   ```
   <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```
6. `mvn spring-boot:run`
7. Access to http://localhost:8080/test.jsp
   -> The following exception occurs:

   ```
   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
   The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
   ```

Comment: Which version of jstl are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.2. It Inherits defaults from Spring Boot.
`<parent><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId><version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version></parent>`

Comment: Ok. Check if any of other dependencies in Pom.xml bringing standard.jar as well transitively, if so exclude this jar...

Comment: I tried adding `<dependency><groupId>taglibs</groupId><artifactId>standard</artifactId><version>1.1.2</version></dependency>` but doesn't work...

Comment: So you disable taglib detection and still expect tags to work...

Comment: Ah, is the cause `server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar`?

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA, I mean to exclude  "standard" dependency if it is being pulled transitively, not adding it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is caused by `server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar`. I will close this question.

Comment: Hey, I'm running the same problem & I have not added this line in my application.properties file

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `jstl` dependency with the `1.2` version. you also need to add `spring-boot-starter-parent` into your `pom.xml`.  you can find dependency below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: why spring-boot-starter-parent is required ?

Comment: What does it mean? Should I add servlet-api 2.5 and downgrade to version 1.4.0.RELEASE?